# Continuously upload images on server using ssh

Tags: c#

i develop one c# windows application for Continuously upload screen shot images.

I want to run 2 or 3 process parallel without hang any other process, currently i use system.timer.thread but not work properly so please give me suggestion which technique is best to Continuously running each process.

Comment: Do you have some Code for us ?

Have you tried it with System.Timers.Timer ?

Comment: [1] System.Threading.Timer m_Timer;
 [2] System.Threading.Timer m_Proc_Start;
 [3] System.Threading.Timer m_ReConnectHost;
============================================
1 st thread running Continuously per second.
m_Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(ProcessTimer_Tick, null, 1000, 0);

2nd(m_Proc_Start) and third(m_ReConnectHost) run when needded.

main concept is 1st thread run Continuously without any break

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not as a comment.